# What to do with old Order Data from ecommerce website/db

Tags: database

I'd like to get advice from experienced people in this subject.

I have a WordPress/WooCommerce website and the order-data is stacking up. I'd like to clean the database of old Order Data, but I don't know that its a good idea to just delete it... so I'm wondering if simply transferring it to another server for storage/later-access is the common practice, is there something more effective or that I should be considering?

Comment: data archive is a complicated subject, if this data is valuable, and I assume it is, I suggest you contact a professional in this area, at least for consultation.

Comment: how much data in GB are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to increase your hardware to meet your needs in my experience. Separate servers are not ideal because then you have more hardware to maintain and what if a client wants to see their order data, now you might need to run against two databases.